# curl -u equivalent in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl

Trying to make

```
curl -u 'clientID:clentSecret' 'https://api.someapi.com'
```

in node, but cannot figure out how to authorize.

I tried

```
"Authorization": "Bearer" + "base64(clientID:clentSecret)",
```

and

```
 "Authorization": "Basic" + "base64(clientID:clentSecret)",
```

and:

```
auth: {
    'user': 'clientID',
    'pass': 'clientSecret'
}
```

but nothing worked. If anyone had similar experience, please help!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your missing a space after `Bearer ` and `Basic ` and base64 is a string not a value

Comment: feel so stupid right now :) thanks man, that's it!

Answer (score 1):

Just a simple fix. You left out a space after "Basic" it should be "Basic  " and "Bearer" should be "Bearer ".
Then your function base64() is within quotes so that will be a string and not a value like you intended, remove the quotes around the function and it will work

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this page: https://curl.trillworks.com/#node , it's very handy. I think you've already got the answer (thanks @Dennington-bear) from comments, but this is worth a look, it can turn a curl command into a Node.js script. I'd recommend reviewing the generated code, so you understand exactly what it's doing, but it's very useful to create a code skeleton from a curl command.

Result (for this command);

```
var request = require('request');

var options = {
    url: 'https://api.someapi.com',
    auth: {
        'user': 'clientID',
        'pass': 'clentSecret'
    }
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body);
    }
}

request(options, callback);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
request.get('http://some.server.com/').auth(clientID, clentSecret, true);
```

You can read more [here](https://github.com/request/request)